# To loop an array with XTemplate in sencha touch 2.1.0

Tags: extjs, sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2, sencha-touch-2.1

The [**Ext.XTemplate Docs**](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2.1.0/#!/api/Ext.XTemplate) says:

The tpl tag and the for operator are used to process the provided data object:

- If the value specified in for is an array, it will auto-fill, repeating the template block inside the tpl tag for each item in the array.
- If for="." is specified, the data object provided is examined.
- While processing an array, the special variable {#} will provide the current array index + 1 (starts at 1, not 0).

I follow the **first rule** and assign the data config of a panel with an array of objects,but it just shows a blank.The code is as below:

```
                  {
                 xtype : 'panel',
                 tpl : new Ext.XTemplate([
                          '<tpl>',
                            '<div>',
                                '{index}',
                            '</div>',
                          '</tpl>'
                 ]),
                 data : [
                         {index : '11'},
                         {index : '12'},
                         {index : '13'}
                 ]
              }
```

So i follow the **second rule** and add a `'for="."'` for the `'<tpl>'`,it works!  So,i want to know whether it really means you have to add a `'for="."'` if you just want to loop an array with Ext.XTemplate ?

**Also**,is it really a bad practice to use the `'for="."'` statement ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, `<tpl for=".">` means iterate over the "active" object. For example, the "active" object changes from the outer array to the inner array because during the iteration we're pointing at the inner array:

```
var tpl = new Ext.XTemplate([
    '<tpl for=".">', // "." points to the outer array
        '<tpl for=".">', // "." points to each inner array
            '{.}',
        '</tpl>',
    '</tpl>'
]);

console.log(tpl.apply([
    [1, 2],
    [3, 4]
]));
```